# What is proper way to block bots/crawlers hitting link/page?

Tags: php, analytics, bots

I am working on analytics and I am getting many in accurate results mostly because of either social media bots or other random bots like BufferBot,DataMinr etc from Twitter.

Is there any Web API/Database of all known bots available which I can use to check if it is a bot or human ?

Or is there any good way to block such kind of bots so that it doesn't effect the stats in terms of analytics?

Comment: Maybe have a look at using Htaccess. This may help: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml

Comment: @TheHumbleRat using that method I may have to manually add in lines for zillions of bots that are roaming around on social media network. hmm

Comment: Can you accept the answer that was most useful? This is the way SO improves.]

Answer (score 1):

You can link to a hidden page that is blocked by robots.txt. When visited, captures the user-agent and IP address of the bot and then appends one or both of them to a .htaccess file which blocks them permanently. It only catches bad bots and is automated so you don't have to do anything to maintain it.

Just make sure you set up the robots.txt file first and then give the good bots a fair chance to read it and update their crawling accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file callled `robots.txt` in your route and add the following lines:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: You're assuming bots will respect that file. Only the good ones do.

Comment: Surely this will block all bots and stop google indexing the site

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to outright block ALL bots, it would be an insane amount of time spent, you could use a .htaccess file or a robots.txt, stopping google indexing the site is easy but blocking bot traffic can get complicated and act like a house of cards
I suggest using this list of crawlers/web-bots http://www.robotstxt.org/db.html

Comment: I want to block bots or user agents that are crawling on social media networks. Problem is it is very hard to find up to date database for all those kinds of bots. Even though I block it they again come using different ip

Comment: Yeah I think if you're issue with it is the fact that you are analysing traffic, attempting to block bots will not b thate useful, because it will give the illusion all bots are blocked, when if the crawlers are aggressive (e.g. spam crawlers looking for mail addresses) they will find a way around your 'block' if you are using google analytics though, I would take a look at this http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/09/05/filter-bots-google-analytics/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=%28opu%20qspwjefe%29&ts=1413813882

Comment: The bot issue is ongoing and there is no real solution as of yet, so I think checking against databases is the most useful, the database I provided is pretty up to date and gets updated often!